# Return a variable as soon as it is set to a certain value. Equality overloading

Tags: c#, equals, short-circuiting

I am overloading the Equality method for value comparison and was wondering if there is a clean way to return `false` as soon as one of the value comparisons returns false. For example, here is the basic idea:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _valOne;
    private int _valTwo;
    private int _valThree;

    public MyClass(int valOne, int valTwo, int valThree)
    {
        _valOne = valOne;
        _valTwo = valTwo;
        _valThree = valThree;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // If the object is null return false
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // If the object is not of MyClass type return false
        MyClass myClass = obj as MyClass;
        if (myClass == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Now compare all the field values
        bool areEqual = false;
        areEqual = (this._valOne == myClass._valOne);
        areEqual = (this._valTwo == myClass._valTwo);
        areEqual = (this._valThree == myClass._valThree);

        return areEqual;
    }
}
```

Say the `_valOne`'s do not equal. The most efficient way to compare is to return `false` as soon as it is known two values are not equal. Something like the following...

```
        // Now compare all the field values
        bool areEqual = false;

        areEqual = (this._valOne == myClass._valOne);
        if (!areEqual)
        {
            return false;
        }

        areEqual = (this._valTwo == myClass._valTwo);
        if (!areEqual)
        {
            return false;
        }

        areEqual = (this._valThree == myClass._valThree);

        return areEqual;
```

So now after the comparison of the `_valOne`s no more value comparisons are made. This seems very repetitive, clunky, and (most importantly) horrible for readability. I want to know if there is any way this code can be reduced to the same effect in a clean way without the use of the && operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an and condition:

```
areEqual = (this._valOne == myClass._valOne) 
    && (this._valTwo == myClass._valTwo) 
    && (this._valThree == myClass._valThree);
```

&& implements short-circuiting by default.

Comment: I thought about doing this but with several fields I thought it might get out of hand. I realize it will work and may be the only solution to this problem but is there any other way that you can think of?

Comment: The only other way is Raze2Dust's other answer, to manually "fall through" each condition and return as soon as one comes back false. The && operator does something very similar with the short-circuited behavior of C# logical operators.

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of the [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) nature of the logical AND (`&&`) operator, like this:

```
return this._valOne == myClass._valOne
    && this._valTwo == myClass._valTwo
    && this._valThree == myClass._valThree;
```

As soon as any one of the comparisons evaluates to false, the whole condition evaluates to false. If all three are true, the condition returns true.

Comment: Like I said to Raze2Dust... Is there any other way than the use of the && operator?

Comment: I don't think so, not sure if you can use reflection for this.

Comment: I would much prefer the && operator over reflection anyways. Thanks for your answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to do this:

```
    if (this._valOne != myClass._valOne)
         return false;
    if (this._valTwo != myClass._valTwo)
         return false;
    if (this._valThree != myClass._valThree)
         return false;
    return true;
```

A matter of choice I guess. I'd think the && one is more readable..